# Simple php in footer not working to call some styling and an url

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress, and I'm having a hard time with a simple php code I want to add in footer.php to display a "|" symbol with 20px of margin and a url only on the site frontpage:

```
<?php
if(is_front_page()){
    echo "<span style='margin: 0 20px;'>|</span><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target='_blank' title='W3C'>Visit W3Schools</a>";
}
?>
```

The following characters are displayed in green by my txt editor as if they were comments:

```
" target='_blank' title='W3C'>Visit W3Schools</a>";
```

With the code above, I'm getting a php error:

> PARSE ERROR: SYNTAX ERROR, UNEXPECTED 'HTTP' (T_STRING), EXPECTING ',' OR ';'

This, is working:

```
<?php if( is_front_page() ) echo '<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>';?>
```

And this, is working too:

```
<?php
if(is_front_page()){
echo "<span style='margin: 0 20px;'>|</span>";
}
?>
```

But somehow I can't combine these two codes. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to escape the `"` in `<a href="http://www.w3schools.com"` or use single quotes, for one thing. Notice the syntax highlighting? Try `<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\"` or `<a href='http://www.w3schools.com'` --- Comments avoid opening up a `C.O.W.` but they do have their place ;-)

Comment: A lot of good answers here, so I'm just going to add that you should stop reading W3Schools because it's garbage.

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Actually @sudowned W3 Schools have recently gotten a bit better. They've updated a few sections on their website, regarding the use of `mysqli_*` functions, finally. ;-) Let's face it, we can't learn everything in "school", the rest comes from "experience".

Comment: Syntax error, simple string escape question - Not going to help anyone in the future. vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going out of "PHP" with the double quote there. You can use this:

```
echo "<span style='margin: 0 20px;'>|</span><a href='http://www.w3schools.com' target='_blank' title='W3C'>Visit W3Schools</a>";
```

You had to use single quotes. You can't use both when going into "String" mode. If you want to use double quote you have to escape it like (with a `\`):

```
echo "<span style='margin: 0 20px;'>|</span><a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\" target='_blank' title='W3C'>Visit W3Schools</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is being commented out is because of your quotes. You have to either use single quotes around your double quotes or escape your quotes.

Here:

```
<?php
if(is_front_page()){
    echo "<span style='margin: 0 20px;'>|</span><a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\" target='_blank'    title='W3C'>Visit W3Schools</a>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `"` characters with `\`

```
if(is_front_page()){
    echo "<span style='margin: 0 20px;'>|</span><a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\" target='_blank' title='W3C'>Visit W3Schools</a>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(is_front_page()){
   echo '<span style="margin: 0 20px;">|</span>';
   echo '<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>';
}

?>
```